# Google Analytics Event Tracking onclick callout within PHP

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

I have been trying to figure out this problem for a few days now with little to no progress, I have a feeling the problem resides in trying to call a javascript function from php. I need to start tracking file downloads on our company website and I've got this working in regular HTML for GA but a lot of our files pull from a database through php and I would like to get this tag working with those files. Nothing is passing through to GA and I can see there is an error when I look at the source in FireFox. Thanks for any insight.

Here is the line of code that's giving me headaches.
`<a target='_blank' href='/$file' onclick='_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'Datasheet', '$filetext']);'><img alt='$filetext' src='/$image' border='0'/></a>`

FireFox shows this part of the code in red as an error, if I take out the onclick portion the error goes away, the page displays fine but nothing is being sent to GA like I mentioned before:

```
<a target='_blank' href='/images/datasheets/IDS-66 Amphe-10G.pdf' onclick='_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'Datasheet', 'Amphe-10G']);'>
```

Here is the full PHP code:

```
<div class="download01">
<div class="download02"></div>
<table style="width: 100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody>
<?


// Make a MySQL Connection
mysql_connect("localhost", "amphenol_web", "ampheweb") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("amphenol_sheets") or die(mysql_error());

// Retrieve all the data from the "distributors" table
$query = "SELECT * FROM datasheets ORDER BY filetext";


$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());




$cols = 6;     // Here we define the number of columns




echo "<table>"; // The container table with $cols columns
    do{
        echo "<tr>";
        for($i=1;$i<=$cols;$i++){   // All the rows will have $cols columns even if
                                    // the records are less than $cols
            $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);


?>
<?

$file = $row['file'];
$image = $row['image'];
$filetext = $row['filetext'];

if ($file == ""){echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";}
    else {echo

        "<td valign='top'>
            <table>
                <tr valign='top'>
<td width='120'>
<div align='center'><a target='_blank' href='/$file' onclick='_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'Datasheet', '$filetext']);'><img alt='$filetext' src='/$image' border='0'/></a><br /><a target='_blank' href='/$file' onclick='_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'Datasheet', '$filetext']);'>$filetext</a></div>
</td>
<tr>
                <td height='25'> </td>
                </tr>
           </table>
        </td>";
}
            }
//          else{
//              echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>"; //If there are no more records at the end, add a blank column
            }
//      }
//  } 

while($row);
    echo "</table>";

?>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not link to your web site. Read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Please show your actual rendered HTML. This has nothing to do with your PHP source code.

Comment: Sorry, I've removed the link and posted what FireFox is showing me.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a problem in your code, where you define analytics tracking:

```
onclick='_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'Datasheet', '$filetext']);'>
```

Your using single quotes, maybe because you use double quotes for your echo, you should replace it with:

```
onclick=\"_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'Datasheet', '$filetext']);\">
```

And still be able to use the same double quotes on echo.

Comment: Jeppe, thanks, I have tried that before and just tried it again and it still doesn't work. It gives me the old "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in" error which requires the single quotes to fix.

Comment: It works, so you might have an error in your settings. Anyway, i posted another answer, doing the same, but in another way.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div align='center'><a target='_blank' href='/$file'"?> onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'Datasheet', '<?php=$filetext ?>']);"><? echo "<img alt='$filetext' src='/$image' border='0'/></a><br /><a target='_blank' href='/$file' onclick='_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'Datasheet', '$filetext']);'>$filetext</a></div>
```

Use this instead then :)

Just replace you whole line of code, starting with "div align='center'>", with the one provided above.

Comment: Jeppe, this worked!!!!!, thank you so much. I had to make some modifications to get it working properly but you got me close enough. Below is the final code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code that works!

```
<div align='center'><a target='_blank' href='/$file'"?> onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'Datasheet', '<?php echo "$filetext"?>']);"><? echo "<img alt='$filetext' src='/$image' border='0'/></a><br /><a target='_blank' href='/$file'"?> onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'Datasheet', '<?php echo "$filetext" ?>']);"><? echo "$filetext</a></div>
```